# Linux Serial Port in C

Tags: c, linux, serial-port

I have written a  program in c for reading and writing serial port.But the problem is I am using while loop and it is continuously sending the command over the serial port.

1. I want to write some command on serial port
2. wait for answer
3. write another command
4. wait for some answer and so on

My code goes like this:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

 int main()

  {   
   printf("\n");
   printf("Please wait till serial Port is  being Initialized .... \n");
   sleep(2);
   printf("\n................. Initializing ................\n");
   sleep(2);
   printf("\n");
   printf("\n\n");
   static int fd = 0;
       int len;
       char res[100];
       char s[100] = " Hellow World";


     struct termios options;

    //==================================================================
    //                  hard coaded port ttyO3
    //==================================================================

      fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY); 
          fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);

     //==================================================================
     //                             Error Handling
     //==================================================================

            if (fd < 0)
      {
      printf("Serial open error %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
          }
      printf("\n");

    printf("\n==================================================\n");

   //==================================================================
   //                 Get the current options for the port...
   //==================================================================

    tcgetattr(fd, &options);


         //==================================================================
    //                Set the baud rates to 115200...
   //==================================================================


    cfsetispeed(&options, B115200);
    cfsetospeed(&options, B115200);

    //=================================================================
   // Enable the receiver and set local mode..
  //==================================================================

    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

//==================================================================    
// Set the new options for the port...
//==================================================================

     tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW,&options);

      while(1)
        {  



      write(fd,s,strlen((char*)s));   
      sleep(1);

      len = read(fd,res,100);  
      if (len < 0)
       {   
         if (errno == EAGAIN)
         {         
               continue;
         }
         else
         { 
             printf("read error %d %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
         } 
       }
     else
      {                   
        res[len < 100 ? len:100] ='\0';
        printf("read %d chars: %s\n",len, res);
      } 
    }
     close(fd);
    }
```

where am I getting wrong.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the file descriptor is opened as non-blocking (`fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);`). You must have some blocking operation if you want to wait for data to be read.

You can make the file descriptor blocking, or use some asynchronous manager like `select`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you make your file descriptor non-blocking (twice), you have to as the system to wait between the steps. A common way to do this is the [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/select) system call, which you can use to wait until there is something to read from the file descriptor.

Can be done something like this:

```
write(...);

fd_set poll_set;
FD_ZERO(&poll_set);
FD_SET(fd, &poll_set);

/* Wait, with no timeout, for something to be readable */
int rc = select(fd + 1, &poll_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
if (rc == -1)
{
    perror("select");
}
else
{
    /* Continue to next step, where you read */
}
```

---

Also note that the read-calls may actually not receive the complete messages in the first attempt. You may have to read multiple times to get the complete message. If your messages are of a fixed size, then read in a loop while decreasing the amount of bytes to read until you have received the complete message. If your message have a end-of-message marker, then read byte by byte until you receive it. If your messages contain a header with the message size, then use the first fixed-size read method twice, once to get the header and once to get the data.

Comment: I would prefer using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) instead of the (obsolete) `select` syscall.